# How do I make my float: right images align with my other images?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a grid-like photo gallery. The format I'm going for is 2 smaller photos on either side of one central picture. However when I try to float my right images they appear way too far down and nothing I've tried will move them up. Any help would be appreciated

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="showsback">
        <img class="showpicleft" src="images/zek.jpg">
        <img class="showpicleft" src="images/kaes.jpg">
        <img class="showpiccenter" src="images/cob.jpg">
        <img class="showpicright" src="images/neil.jpg">
        <img class="showpicright" src="images/gav.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#showsback {
    background-image: url(images/SDSOback.jpeg);
    background-size: 25%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1em #f2f1ba solid;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
} 

.showpiccenter {
    margin-top: .5em;
    max-width: 30%;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    clear: both;
} 

.showpicleft {
    max-width: 30%;
    margin-top: 1.25em;
    margin-right: .5em;
    margin-left: .5em;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.showpicright {
    margin-top: 1.25em;
    max-width: 30%;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: After posting this I figured out a solution. I removed all of the clear elements from the CSS, and just added a style="clear: both;" tag to the 2nd left image. This, and changing the order that the images appear, gave me the result I wanted.

Comment: Hi Zachary, I just spent some time writing a codepen on this, maybe you like the result? https://codepen.io/cainytheslave/pen/xxYpRjr